# React component not updating on final dispatch and update of redux state

Tags: reactjs, redux, action

I am fairly new to React and Redux and I have an issue with my component not updating on the final dispatch that updates a redux store.  I am using a thunk to preload some data to drive various pieces of my site.  I can see the thunk working and the state updating seemingly correctly but when the data fetch success dispatch happens, the component is not seeing a change in state and subsequently not re rendering.  the interesting part is that the first dispatch which sets a loading flag is being seen by the component and it is reacting correctly.  Here is my code:

## actions

```
import { programsConstants } from '../constants';
import axios from 'axios'

export const programsActions = {
    begin,
    success,
    error,
};

export const loadPrograms = () => dispatch => {
    dispatch(programsActions.begin());

    axios
        .get('/programs/data')
        .then((res) => {
            dispatch(programsActions.success(res.data.results));
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            dispatch(programsActions.error(err.message));
        });
};

function begin() {
    return {type:programsConstants.BEGIN};
}
function success(data) {
    return {type:programsConstants.SUCCESS, payload: data};
}
function error(message) {
    return {type:programsConstants.ERROR, payload:message};
}
```

## reducers

```
import {programsConstants} from '../constants';
import React from "react";

const initialState = {
    data: [],
    loading: false,
    error: null
};

export function programs(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case programsConstants.BEGIN:
            return fetchPrograms(state);
        case programsConstants.SUCCESS:
            return populatePrograms(state, action);
        case programsConstants.ERROR:
            return fetchError(state, action);
        case programsConstants.EXPANDED:
            return programsExpanded(state, action);
        default:
            return state
    }
}

function fetchPrograms(state = {}) {
    return { ...state, data: [], loading: true, error: null };
}

function populatePrograms(state = {}, action) {
   return { ...state, data: action.payload, loading: false, error: null };
}

function fetchError(state = {}, action) {
    return { ...state, data: [], loading: false, error: action.payload };
}
```

## component

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { Header, Footer, Sidebar } from "../../components";
import dashboardRoutes from "../../routes/dashboard.jsx";
import Loading from "../../components/Loading/Loading";
import {loadPrograms} from "../../actions/programs.actions";

class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(loadPrograms());
  }

  render() {
    const { error, loading } = this.props;

    if (loading) {
      return <div><Loading loading={true} /></div>
    }
    if (error) {
      return <div style={{ color: 'red' }}>ERROR: {error}</div>
    }

    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <Sidebar {...this.props} routes={dashboardRoutes} />
        <div className="main-panel" ref="mainPanel">
          <Header {...this.props} />
          <Switch>
            {dashboardRoutes.map((prop, key) => {
              let Component = prop.component;
              return (
                  <Route path={prop.path} component={props => <Component {...props} />} key={key} />
              );
            })}
          </Switch>
          <Footer fluid />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  loading: state.programs.loading,
  error: state.programs.error
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Dashboard);
```

The component should receive updated props from the success dispatch and re render with the updated data.  Currently the component only re renders on the begin dispatch and shows the loading component correctly but doesn't re render with the data is retrieved and updated to the state by the thunk.

I've researched this for a couple days and the generally accepted cause for the component not getting a state refresh is inadvertent state mutation rather than returning a new state.  I don't think I'm mutating the state but perhaps I am.

Any help would much appreciated!

## Update 1

As requested here's the code for creating the store and combining the reducers

store:

```
const loggerMiddleware = createLogger();
const composeEnhancers =
    typeof window === 'object' &&
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ ?
        window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({
        }) : compose;

const enhancer = composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(
        thunk,
        loggerMiddleware)
);

export const store = createStore(rootReducer, enhancer);
```

reducer combine:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { alert } from './alert.reducer';
import { programs } from './programs.reducer';
import { sidenav } from './sidenav.reducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  programs,
  sidenav,
  alert
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Comment: Could you share a live demo?

Comment: can you post how you create your store and combine the reducers ?

Comment: I don't think I can share a live demo @ Niraj Kaushal.

Comment: The code you requested has been added to the question as Update 1 @Ali

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd param is expected to be **[preloadedState]**:

```
export const store = createStore(rootReducer, {} , enhancer);
```

`axios.get` return a `promise` that you need to `await` for to get your data:

Try this:

```
   export const loadPrograms = () => async (dispatch) => {
      dispatch(programsActions.begin());

      try {
        const res = await axios.get('/programs/data');
        const data = await res.data;
        console.log('data recieved', data)
        dispatch(programsActions.success(data.results));
      } catch (error) {
        dispatch(programsActions.error(error));
      }
    };


const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  loading: state.programs.loading,
  error: state.programs.error,
  data: state.programs.data,
});
```

Action Call

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { loadPrograms } from '../../actions/programs.actions';

class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // Try to call you action this way:
    this.props.loadProgramsAction(); // <== Look at this
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  loading: state.programs.loading,
  error: state.programs.error,
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {
    loadProgramsAction: loadPrograms,
  },
)(Dashboard);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @Hend El-Sahli.  Unfortunately, this produces the exact same result I'm already experiencing.  Data is getting into the redux store correctly but component is not registering the update and thus not re rendering.

Comment: @shifuharris check out the edit please ... regarding `mapStateToProps`

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I'm still seeing the same behavior as before though.  I had that in there before thinking along the same lines but took it out when it still didn't work and thinking that the update to the loading flag was enough of a change to trigger the re-rendering.  Thanks again!

Comment: I have and it looks fine.

Comment: Alright :) ... one more trial ... try to call your action the way I did in the edit...

Comment: Thanks @Hend El-Sahli.  I tried it but got the same results.

Comment: @shifuharris your code is almost exactly the same that I'm having ... last thing I'd suggest is to try to create your store like that `createStore(reducers, {}, compose(applyMiddleware(Thunk)));` ... maybe the condition you're having is the reason for that ... and you're welcome anyway

Answer (score 0):

After three days of research and refactoring, I finally figured out the problem and got it working. Turns out that the version of react-redux is was using (6.0.1) was the issue. Rolled back to 5.1.1 and everything worked flawlessly. Not sure if something is broken in 6.0.1 or if I was just using wrong.